# Doesn't IKVM.net support generics (type parameters)?

Tags: c#, java, generics, type-erasure, ikvm

I statically recompiled a Java lib which used generics a lot, like `Collection<?>`, but the emitted .NET dll only uses `Collection`, not with type parameters. How come?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java generics are dealt by the Java compiler and are converted to non-generic version at compile time. This is different from .NET where the CLR has first class support for type parameters. At the bytecode level, `ArrayList<T>` will just be a simple `ArrayList`.

To quote [Java docs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/generics/):

> Generics are implemented by the Java compiler as a front-end conversion called *erasure*, which is the process of translating or rewriting code that uses generics into non-generic code (that is, maps the new syntax to the current JVM specification). **In other words, this conversion erases all generic type information; all information between angle brackets is erased.** For example, `LinkedList<Integer>` will become `LinkedList`. Uses of other type variables are replaced by the upper bound of the type variable (for example, `Object`), and when the resulting code is not type correct, a cast to the appropriate type is inserted.

Comment: I dislike Java generics for this reason. Generics should have been a major feature, but instead it wasn't much more than syntactic sugar for avoiding casting `object`s to a specific type. Sugar is wonderful, but it could have been so much more. Mumble types and so do actually add value though, so it's not all bad.

Comment: @Joren, you're being unnecessarily harsh on generics. While type erasure is certainly dissappointing, generics are certainly a clear step up over having to cast from Object as we are now able to have all the compile-time guarantees of the Java type system with our genericized classes.

Comment: But the generic information is still available in the compiled class file as metadata (otherwise `javac` wouldn't be able to check generics). Couldn't IKVM use this information?